# Put the page numbers right next to the chapter names in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, multitoc

In the table of contents, I'd like to put the page numbers right next to the chapter names like so:

[image]

Preferably I'd like to add a `/` between the chapter name and the page number like so:

`1. Intro / 2`

I've read one or two tutorials and tried several things but couldn't do it. How to do it? Note that I'd like to do it without changing the `extbook` class and without giving up the `multitoc` package

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,14pt]{extbook}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
\renewcommand*{\multicolumntoc}{2}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt} % remove vertical column line
% \addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}} % remove page no
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{} % remove dots

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\pagebreak

\chapter{Intro}
Some text
\pagebreak
\chapter{Unit with more and more text}
Some text

\pagebreak

Some more text

\pagebreak

Some more and more text
\chapter{Termination Unit}
Some text
\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see that the Question was purely technical, and has been suitably Answered yet still I ask whether you're sure you want to do that? Keeping the numbers set right, as with the black originals in your illustration, makes the table easier to read and the numbers easier to find. Floating the numbers X spaces after a chapter name of varying length will make everything harder, even if only slightly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With package `tocloft` you can use

```latex
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\:/\:}
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftpnumalign}{l}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,14pt]{extbook}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
\renewcommand*{\multicolumntoc}{2}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\:/\:}
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftpnumalign}{l}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Intro}
Some text
\chapter{Unit with more and more text}
Some text
\clearpage
Some more text
\clearpage
Some more and more text
\chapter{Termination Unit}
Some text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works quite fine. One more thing, though: How to change the font sizes of the chapter names and page numbers in ToC? They seem to overtake the font size from the doc class definition line where it's set to 14pt; I'd like to use smaller font, say 10pt and preferably change the typeface too.  I've tried some `renewcommand` stuff but it didn't worked out.

Comment: Redefine `\cftchapfont` and `\cftchappagefont`, eg. `\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\small}` and `\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\small}`.